# $H$ Hilbert, $\ker L \neq H \Rightarrow (\ker L )^{\perp} \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

> If $H$ is a Hilbert space on $\mathbb{C}, L : H \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is linear and bounded, $\ker L \neq H $ then $ (\ker L )^{\perp} \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace.$

It seems like a quite easy result but don't know where to start actually. Any suggestion? I am looking for a proof which relies only on the definitions of the actors.

Comment: What is known about $L$?

Answer (score 0):

Given that $L$ is continuous, $\ker L$ is a closed subspace of $H$. Since $\ker(L) \neq H$, a corollary of Hahn-Banach tells you that there is a non-zero continuous linear functional $f:H\to\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
f(x) = 0 \quad \forall x\in \ker L
$$
By Riesz Representation, there is a vector $y \in H$ such that
$$
f(x) = \langle x, y\rangle
$$
Now $y \in (\ker L)^{\perp}$ and $y\neq 0$.